# Location of global variables with DWARF (and relocation)

Tags: c, elf, dwarf

When dynamically linking a binary with libraries, relocation information is used to bind the variables/functions of the different ELF objects. However DWARF is not affected by relocation: how is a debugger supposed to resolve global variables?

Let's say I have liba.so (a.c) defining  a global variable (using GNU/Linux with GCC or Clang):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 10;

int test(void) {
  printf("&foo=%p\n", &foo);
}
```

and an program b linked against liba.so (b.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  test();
  printf("&foo=%p\n", &foo);  
  return 0;
}
```

I expect that "foo" will be instanciated in liba.so
but in fact it is instanciated in both liba.so and b:

```
$ ./b 
&foo=0x600c68 # <- b .bss
&foo=0x600c68 # <- b .bss
```

The foo variable which is used (both by b and by lib.so) is in the .bss of b
and not in liba.so:

```
[...]
0x0000000000600c68 - 0x0000000000600c70 is .bss
[...]
0x00007ffff7dda9c8 - 0x00007ffff7dda9d4 is .data in /home/foo/bar/liba.so
0x00007ffff7dda9d4 - 0x00007ffff7dda9d8 is .bss in  /home/foo/bar/liba.so
```

The foo variable is instanciated twice:

- once in liba.so (this instance is not used when linked with program b)
- once in b (this instance is used instance of the other in b).

(I don't really understand why the variable is instanciated in the executable.)

There is only a declaration in b (as expected) in the DWARF informations:

```
$ readelf -wi b
[...]
<1><ca>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_variable)
  <cb>   DW_AT_name        : foo      
  <cf>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
  <d0>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3        
  <d1>   DW_AT_type        : <0x57>   
  <d5>   DW_AT_external    : 1        
  <d5>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
[...]
```

and a location is found in liba.so:

```
$ readelf -wi liba.so
[...]
<1><90>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_variable)
  <91>   DW_AT_name        : foo      
  <95>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
  <96>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3        
  <97>   DW_AT_type        : <0x57>   
  <9b>   DW_AT_external    : 1        
  <9b>   DW_AT_location    : 9 bloc d'octets: 3 d0 9 20 0 0 0 0 0     (DW_OP_addr: 2009d0)
[...]
```

This address is the location of the (unsued) instance of foo in liba.so (.data).

- I end up with 2 instances of the foo global variable (on in liba.so and one in b);
- only the first one can be seen with DWARF;
- only the secone one is used.

How is the debugger supposed to resolve the foo global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really understand why the variable is instanciated in the executable.

You can find the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter4-84604/index.html).

> How is the debugger supposed to resolve the foo global variable

The debugger reads *symbol tables* (in addition to debug info), and `foo` *does* get defined in both the main executable `b`, and in `liba.so`:

```
nm b | grep foo
0000000000600c68 B foo
```

Answer (score 0):

(I read the Oracle doc provided by @Employed Russian.)

The global variable reinstanciation is done for non-PIC code in order to dereference the variable in a non-PIC way without patching the non-PIC code:

- a copy of the variable is done for **non-PIC code**;
- the variable is instanciated in the executable;
- a copy relocation instruction is used to copy the data from the source shared objet at dynamic linking time;
- the instance in the shared objet is not used (after the relocation copy has been done).

Copy relocation instructions:

```
$readelf -r b

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x638 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000600c58  000300000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000600ca8  001200000005 R_X86_64_COPY     0000000000600ca8 foo + 0
```

For functions, the GOT+PLT technique is used the same way they are used in PIC code.